# Save and Redraw in a loop Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, cgaffinetransform

I am trying to draw gauge ticks as in the below image in a loop.

[image: Gauge Ticks]

I followed the below steps:

```
1. create a CAShapeLayer and CALayer
2. for loop 
3. draw center top line with UIBezier
4. rotate the layer in the loop
5. add CAShapeLayer to the CALayer with .addSubLayer
5. end loop
```

**Code**

```
let angle = CGFloat(Double.pi / 180 * 10)

turnLayer.frame            = self.bounds
self.layer.addSublayer(turnLayer)
let strokeColor            = UIColor.black.cgColor
thickLayer.frame           = frame
thickLayer.strokeColor     = strokeColor
thickLayer.fillColor       = UIColor.clear.cgColor
thickLayer.lineWidth       = 8.0


for idx in -10...10 {
    var p: CGPoint = CGPoint.init(x: bounds.width/2, y: bounds.height/8)
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: p)
    p = CGPoint.init(x: bounds.width/2, y: bounds.height/8 + 32)
    path.addLine(to: p)
    thickLayer.path = path.cgPath
    thickLayer.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angle * CGFloat(idx)))
    turnLayer.addSublayer(thickLayer)

}
```

**Problem**

I am lost about how to save and redraw the center top line

Comment: What do you mean by "I am lost about how to save and redraw the center top line"?

Comment: It is very easy in android with canvas.rotate and canvas.save methods and it is a nice way of drawing instead of dealing with trigonometry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than adding a bunch of rotated layers, it might be easier to have a single `CAShapeLayer` with the strokes for all the ticks, e.g.,

```
let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3
shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

let maxRadius = min(view.bounds.width, view.bounds.height) / 2
let center = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.midX, y: view.bounds.midY)

let path = UIBezierPath()

for i in 0 ... 16 {
    let angle = -(CGFloat.pi / 2.0) + CGFloat.pi / 2.0 * (CGFloat(i - 8)) / 9.0
    let outerRadius = maxRadius
    let innerRadius = maxRadius - (i % 2 == 0 ? 20 : 10)
    path.move(to: point(angle: angle, from: center, radius: outerRadius))
    path.addLine(to: point(angle: angle, from: center, radius: innerRadius))
}

shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
```

Where

```
func point(angle: CGFloat, from center: CGPoint, radius: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: center.x + radius * cos(angle), y: center.y + radius * sin(angle))
}
```

That yields:

[image]

Obviously, tweak the `angle`, `innerRadius` and `outerRadius` to suit your purposes, but this illustrates an easier way to render all of those tick marks.

---

If comments, you seemed to object to the above approach, and effectively asked if it is possible to save a snapshot of a view (presumably so you can later show this image in an image view). Yes, it is:

```
extension UIView {
    func snapshot(afterScreenUpdates: Bool = false) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, 0)
        drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: afterScreenUpdates)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return image
    }
}
```

So, following up with your question of "can I add the shapelayer and save a snapshot", the answer is yes, you can

```
let shapeLayer = ...
view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
let image = view.snapshot(afterScreenUpdates: true)
```

Then, if you wanted to use that snapshot, you'd have to remove the `CAShapeLayer` and then show the snapshot in some image view:

```
shapeLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
imageView.image = image
```

Obviously, that's an incredibly inefficient approach (particularly because you have to use `afterScreenUpdates` value of `true` if you want recently added content to be included in the snapshot).

If you really wanted to efficiently create an image of all the ticks, you'd probably just `stroke` the `UIBezierPath` directly to an image context. All you'd need to know was the size of the `UIImage` to create:

```
func tickImage(size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)

    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.lineWidth = 3

    let maxRadius = size.width / 2
    let center = CGPoint(x: size.width / 2, y: size.height)

    for i in 0 ... 16 {
        let angle = -(CGFloat.pi / 2.0) + CGFloat.pi / 2.0 * (CGFloat(i - 8)) / 9.0
        let outerRadius = maxRadius
        let innerRadius = maxRadius - (i % 2 == 0 ? 20 : 10)
        path.move(to: point(angle: angle, from: center, radius: outerRadius))
        path.addLine(to: point(angle: angle, from: center, radius: innerRadius))
    }

    UIColor.lightGray.setStroke()
    path.stroke()

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return image
}
```

That having been said, I'm not sure why you'd do that instead of the `CAShapeLayer` in the beginning of this answer. I'd only do this "create `UIImage`" approach if I needed to save/upload this snapshot for use at some later date. Otherwise `CAShapeLayer` is a fine approach.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but if you know if it is possible to rotate and save in swift i will apreciate this.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Add the rotated `CAShapeLayer`, and take snapshot, remove `CAShapeLayer`, repeat. See revised answer. But that's an incredibly inefficient approach. If you really wanted to create a `UIImage` with the gauge tick marks, I'd create the image context for the tick marks, `stroke` the tick marks, and then save the image. It's more cumbersome than just creating `CAShapeLayer` with all the tick marks up front, but it also works. See revised answer.

Comment: By the way, I'm still not rotating in my "`stroke` to image context" approach, but rather using trigonometry. If you really want to "rotate and stroke", you can do that using core graphics directly to the image context, but (a) save context state; (b) rotate context; (c) stroke single tick mark; (d) restore context state; (e) repeat. It strikes me as an unnecessarily complicated approach, but you could do that if you really wanted.

Comment: Thanks again for detailed answer which also points to the performance concerns. I am gonna use first approach.